# Read the logback.xml from a system variable value

Tags: java, xml, maven

I have a project that I built it using maven jar plugin.For logging i am using logback.and I want my logback.xml be out of the executableJar.For reading the logback.xml i have set a new environment variable with a value that i put my logback.xml in it.how can I tell my project to go use this variable in order to find the config file?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this manual:

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution

You can use command like below:

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml chapters.configuration.MyApp1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.  In your jar (src/resources/) add a skeleton logback.xml like so:

```
<configuration>
    <include resource="file:${LOG_CONFIG_DIR}/logback-app.xml"/>
</configuration>
```

Then at startup you can use a logback-app.xml outside the jar which looks like this

```
<included>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{60} %mdc{applicationName} %mdc{environment}
                %mdc{gearid} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.apache" level="ERROR"/>

    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</included>
```

Then at start you can wire in the external file like this :

java ... -DLOG_CONFIG_DIR=/directory....